# JavaScript won't write data in Firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to store data on Firebase using JavaScript through HTML input form.

I have tried every possible solution but it simply won't write even though the same code worked before on the same database

What is the wrong with my code and why it did it suddenly stop working?

This is my HTML form:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="myform"><br>
<input id="tournumber" type="text" placeholder="tour number" /><br> <br>   
<input id="tname" type="text" placeholder="name" />    <br><br>

<input id="arname" type="text" placeholder="email" />    <br><br>
<input id="enname" type="text" placeholder="date" />    <br><br>
<input id="duration" type="text" placeholder="national Id" /><br><br>    
<input id="guide" type="text" placeholder="national Id" />    <br><br>
<input id="date" type="text" placeholder="national Id" />    <br><br>
<br><br>
<a href="#" onclick="sub()"> <button id = 'submit' type="submit">Submit</button></a>
</form>
```

And this is my JavaScript script

```
function sub()
{
        
        
var tournumber= document.getElementById('tournumber').value;
var tname= document.getElementById('tname').value;
var arname= document.getElementById('arname').value;
var ename= document.getElementById('enname').value;
var duration= document.getElementById('duration').value;
var guide= document.getElementById('guide').value;
var tdate= document.getElementById('date').value;
       var artype = "test";
        var entype = "Guided by a guide";
        
savedata(tournumber, tname, arname, ename, duration, guide, tdate, artype, entype);

}

function savedata(tournumber, tname, arname, ename, duration, guide, tdate, artype, entype)
{
  var tourRef = firebase.database().ref('tours/Available_tours')
    .child(parseInt(tournumber))
    .set({dayAR:arname, dayEN:ename, duration:duration, 
          guide:guide, tourDate:tdate, tourName:tname, typeAR:artype, typeEN:entype});   

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem is caused by `method="post"` in that when you click the Submit button, the browser submit's the form to the new path specified by `action=""` (which resolves to the same page).

Removing the `method="post"` and changing the `onclick` from the `<a>` to the form's `onsubmit` handler yields the following code:

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="return sub(this)" id="myform"><br>
<input id="tournumber" type="text" placeholder="tour number" />    <br><br>
<input id="tname" type="text" placeholder="name" />    <br><br>
<input id="arname" type="text" placeholder="email" />    <br><br>
<input id="enname" type="text" placeholder="date" />    <br><br>
<input id="duration" type="text" placeholder="national Id" />    <br><br>
<input id="guide" type="text" placeholder="national Id" />    <br><br>
<input id="date" type="text" placeholder="national Id" />    <br><br>
<br><br>
<button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

By passing in the form using `return sub(this)`, you can eliminate many `document.getElementById(id)` calls and replace them with `form[id]`.

```js
function sub(form) {
    var tournumber = form['tournumber'].value;
    var tname = form['tname'].value;
    var arname = form['arname'].value;
    var ename = form['enname'].value;
    var duration = form['duration'].value;
    var guide = form['guide'].value;
    var tdate = form['date'].value;
    var artype = "test";
    var entype = "Guided by a guide";

    savedata(tournumber, tname, arname, ename, duration, guide, tdate, artype, entype);

    return false; // tell form to stay on this page
}
```

#### Other suggested changes

In your `savedata()` function, you should return the Promise returned by `set()` so that you can handle any errors.

```js
function savedata(tournumber, tname, arname, ename, duration, guide, tdate, artype, entype)
{
  return firebase.database().ref('tours/Available_tours')
    .child(parseInt(tournumber))
    .set({dayAR:arname, dayEN:ename, duration:duration, 
          guide:guide, tourDate:tdate, tourName:tname, typeAR:artype, typeEN:entype});
}

// e.g. savedata(...).then(() => console.log('saved successfully'), (err) => console.error('save failed: ', err))
```

I'd avoid calling a function with so many arguments as adding or removing data entries could be a pain in the future, and instead opt to pass an object instead.

```js
function sub(form) {
    var tournumber = form['tournumber'].value;

    var newData = {
      dayAR: form['arname'].value,
      dayEN: form['enname'].value,
      duration: form['duration'].value,
      guide: form['guide'].value,
      tourDate: form['date'].value,
      tourName: form['tname'].value,
      typeAR: "test",
      typeEN: "Guided by a guide"
    };

    savedata(tournumber, newData);

    return false; // tell form to stay on this page
}

function savedata(tournumber, data)
{
    return firebase.database().ref('tours/Available_tours')
      .child(parseInt(tournumber))
      .set(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much 
your answer did not solve my problem but it helped with making the code more efficient 

i solved the problem by creating a new firebase project and database 
thank you again sir

Answer (score 0):

You have to write this information to a specific document with and ID.
For example:

```
function savedata(SOME_ID,tournumber, tname, arname, ename, duration, guide, tdate, artype, entype)
{
  var tourRef = firebase.database().ref('tours/Available_tours/'+SOME_ID)
    .child(parseInt(tournumber))
    .set({dayAR:arname, dayEN:ename, duration:duration, 
          guide:guide, tourDate:tdate, tourName:tname, typeAR:artype, typeEN:entype});   

}
```

You can find more about this here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write

Comment: the problem was with the firebase project and databse
i have created a new project and the same code worked fine 
thank you for answering my question